# I can't ask questions: how do I improve previously asked questions that have no margin for improvement?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I asked some petty questions in the past and hence I cannot ask questions anymore. I would like to lift that ban but it seems there are only two ways to do it.

1) Improve previous questions.

2) Wait for six months before asking a new question.

Can anyone give me suggestion regarding how I can improve the previous questions.?

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/51083678) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/47021419) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/45867755) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/45846403))

Comment: @SamuelLiew Couldn't see those questions in my deleted questions tab. Thank You. How do I undelete questions deleted by community?

Comment: Are you able to edit those questions first? If yes please do so before flagging your question for moderator review.

Comment: The duplicate I linked has a section about editing your prior questions, with several links to excellent how-to guides to make questions good. As Samuel said, when you've done that, you can moderator-flag deleted questions for undeletion.

Comment: @Magisch It is simply the bad question. Like real bad w/o any research stuff and newbie question. Idk really how I can edit and make it good

Comment: The duplicate also contains other strategies to lift yourself out of the post ban, such as using your one-chance every 6 months question to be really good and get you out via it getting upvoted.

Comment: @Magisch I have read that but that is not what I am really asking. I am asking like can anyone suggest me how to improve my previous questions, not in a general term but specifically related to my questions.

Comment: If that is not too much help to ask

Comment: @Many it is, a bit. Simply because you come here and do the same mistake you did in your SO questions: lack of research. Where is your try to improve your questions? Do you have a specific question in mind and an idea how you'll improve it? Right now it feels like you are putting all the improvement work on the community, instead of coming from you

Comment: Also understand that this site can be well used even if/when you can't ask a question. For most of the main programming categories, most of the most common and helpful questions have already been asked, and perhaps what you will want to work on is your search-of-site skills, to allow you to find those duplicates to your problems and use them to help you solve them. I would venture that 90% of the folks who get banned do so because they don't understand that this site is best used as a search-first site.